# Is it possible for a hacker to bypass upload php file?

Tags: php, file-upload, html

I wanna give a filtering system in my script.
here it is :

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png","bmp");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if (in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
//here is rst of codes
?>
```

Means my script will check extension for uploading file with `explode` . 
So, now is it possible for a hacker to bypass this system ? And upload  malicious code script ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A lot can still go wrong given an application that contains this small snip of code.

1. An attacker could use a [local file include vulnerability to obtain 
   remote code execution](http://www.exploit-db.com/papers/12992/) by putting PHP code within the metadata of
   an uploaded image.
2. An attacker could potentially write an image with a valid file
   extension in any directory using [directory traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack).
3. In older versions of PHP an attacker could use a null byte to
   control    the extension by truncating the filename,  but [FILE
   functions will escape null bytes as of PHP 5.3.4.](https://bugs.php.net/39863%E2%80%8E)

Comment: 1 > it is not possible without php extension. 
3 > it is not possible for now a days. 
2 > will you please explain it ? i think this may be serious matter.

Comment: @slash-bang the whole point of #1 is that **it does not need a .php extension**,  the example used php code in the meta data of an image.  You need to read the links provided and ask more informed questions.  Seriously.

Comment: I am reading those.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

A common way to bypass simple check like the one you are using is to use a real picture file (e.g. a JPEG) and add a remote shell inside the picture's comment.

To check whether your implementation is vulnerable or not, just take any valid picture and add the following basic shell as a comment with your editor of choice (e.g. Photoshop, GIMP):

```
<?php echo "<pre>"; system($_GET['cmd']); ?>
```

When the picture gets successfully uploaded, try calling it with the *cmd* parameter set to a simple command (e.g. */upload/shell.jpg?cmd=ls*). If the folder where it gets uploaded executes any kind of files, then the shell should be active.

Note: some PHP functions, like the *system* one used here, could be disabled. In this case, there are a number or different functions that can be tried in order to execute commands.

Comment: The OP has a white-list of file extensions which should prevent `shell.php` from being uploaded.

Comment: Hei, How can you upload a .php file ? 
Without .php is it can be possible to execute php code ?

Comment: @Rook: The file that is gonna be uploaded is a valid jpeg (with a .jpeg/.jpg extension), so the whitelisting should be bypassed. The PHP code needs to be placed inside the comment.

Comment: @slash-bang: You'll be uploading a proper .jpeg file, just the comment inside it will be PHP code. The shell will run if the server allows JPEG files to be executed, so it will depend.

Comment: @Gurzo this would require an LFI or a misconfigured server.  Perhaps you should update your post to specify this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Although by itself it is not 100% secure, I would suggest that you check for the MIME type of the file rather than an extension using [`exif_imagetype`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php). It's a good step to help validate the image.

Anyone can stick malicious PHP code into a .gif file, and with many fcgi/fpm's and routing, it will get parsed by PHP if it gets uploaded to a web facing directory and the attacker browses to this page.

To circumvent this, you want to make sure your files are not in your webroot, and if you are using some kind of routing or url rewriting, turn off PHP-FPM/mod_php for `.gif|.jpg|.jpeg` etc. This will help you out in the long run as well. Unless there is a 0day out there somewhere, the uploading of a file does not run an `eval()` on it, so the file has to be accessed directly for it to be malicious.

In addition to this, I would suggest you run `array getimagesize ( string $filename [, array &$imageinfo ] )` on your image. If it returns `0`, it is not a valid image. You do not need `GD` for this to work either.

Comment: Anyone can hack mime type by edit header, and getimagesize by just input php code into a image file.

Comment: right, but it's a better solution than looking for an extension alone. If you check for MIME-type, extension and getimagesize together, it would be a bit more difficult to spoof, but of course it's still possible.